# Regex grab first and last item separated by pipes in a string python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

> The|DT|I-MISC Oxford|NNP|I-MISC Companion|NNP|I-MISC to|TO|I-MISC Philosophy|NNP|I-MISC says|VBZ|O ,|,|O "|LQU|O there|EX|O is|VBZ|O no|DT|O single|JJ|O defining|VBG|O position|NN|O that|IN|O all|DT|O anarchists|NNS|O hold|VBP|O ,|,|O and|CC|O those|DT|O considered|VBN|O anarchists|NNS|O at|IN|O best|JJS|O share|NN|O a|DT|O certain|JJ|O family|NN|O resemblance|NN|O .|.|O "|RQU|O
>   In|IN|O the|DT|O

I want to get the first and last item of each triple. So for The|DT|I-MISC, I want (The, I-MISC). 
This was my implementation, and I was wondering if there was anything better and more stable.

```
#STRAT 2: get first and third. this seems more stable
pat = r'((?<= ).+?(?=\|))'
nerpat = r'(?<=[A-Z]\|).+?(?= )'
print zip(re.findall(pat, y), re.findall(nerpat, y))
```

Mistakes in my pattern include: the NNP|I-ORG below.

> ('consequently', 'O'), ('refrain', 'I-ORG'), ('from', 'I-ORG'), ('committing', 'I-ORG'), ('to', 'I-ORG'), ('any', 'O'), ('particular', 'NNP|I-ORG'), ('method', 'O'),

related to this section of text:

> ,|,|O whereas|IN|O anarchists|NNS|O must|MD|O always|RB|O have|VB|O anarchy|NN|O as|IN|O their|PRP$|O end|NN|O and|CC|O consequently|RB|O refrain|VB|O from|IN|O committing|VBG|O to|TO|O any|DT|O particular|JJ|O method|NN|O of|IN|O achieving|VBG|O it|PRP|O .|.|O

Comment: Why don't you use the **csv** module with a custom dialect?

Comment: @cristianCiupitu can you explain with an example?

Comment: `csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')`. See also the example from the `csv.reader` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the matched group form index 1 and 2 to get the first and last item of each triple

```
              ([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)
First item-----^^^^^^ ^      ^ ^^^^^-----------Last item
       First Pipe_____|      |_______Second pipe
```

here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/xE6pT6/2)

**Note:** Add `\s` to match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]` as suggested in below comments.

sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)')
test_str = u"..."

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Pattern explanation:

```
 (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^|]+                    any character except: '|' (1 or more times)
  )                        end of \1

  \|                       '|'
  [^|]+                    any character except: '|' (1 or more times)
  \|                       '|'

  (                        group and capture to \2:
    [^|]+                    any character except: '|' (1 or more times)
  )                        end of \2
```

Read more about

- [Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: I'm getting the following mistakes: [('\nThe', 'I-MISC Oxford'), ('NNP', 'NNP'), ('I-MISC to', 'I-MISC Philosophy'), ('NNP', 'VBZ'), ('O ,', 'O "'), ('LQU', 'EX'), ('O is', 'O no'), ('DT', 'JJ'), ('O defining', 'O position'), ('NN', 'IN'), ('O all', 'O anarchists'), ('NNS', 'VBP'), ('O ,', 'O and'), ('CC', 'DT'), ('O considered', 'O anarchists'), ('NNS', 'IN'), ('O best', 'O share'), ('NN', 'DT'), ('O certain', 'O family'), ('NN', 'NN'), ('O .', 'O "'), ('RQU', 'IN'), ('O the', 'O end'), ('NN', ','), ('O for', 'O anarchist')

Comment: i've been having a bit of trouble understanding grouping. is this how it works: you put parens around the sections you want, and then you put the rest of the structure in between. when you use findall, it only grabs the things in parens. can you also backreference?

Comment: can you explain this thing '[^|]+'

Comment: you just need to capture it using parenthesis. Let me update the explanation.

Comment: excellent. last question. if you use '^' inside a character group bracket, it means exclude?

Comment: also to make the answer complete, i do think you need a \s at the end like this: pat = '([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+\s)'

Comment: or: pat = '([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)(?=\s)'

Answer (score 1):

You can just split the string using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re
terms = re.split('[| ]', y)
print zip(terms[::3], terms[2::3])
```

Another one that I like is to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
filter = itemgetter(0, 2)
print [filter(triplet.split('|')) for triplet in y.split()]
```

Comment: i tried. the fact that there's a space after the third item makes it difficult. I get results like these for terms[::3]: ['\nThe', 'DT', 'I-MISC Oxford', 'NNP', 'I-MISC Companion', 'NNP', 'I-MISC to', 'TO', 'I-MISC Philosophy',

Comment: Ok got it, check it now

Comment: hm.. .i still get mistakes: certain', 'family', 'resemblance', '.', '"', 'IN', 'DT', 'NN', ',', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJ', 'NNP', 'NNP', 'LQU', 'DT', 'NNS', 'VBP', 'RBR', 'JJ', 'IN', 'JJ', ',', 'DT', 'JJR', 'JJ', 'IN', 'JJ', '.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'I-PER', 'I-PER', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O\nGodwin'

Comment: This is strange, it works perfectly for me, can you tell me exactly the input that gives error and the output?